# Send file to MVC Controller

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, file, spring-mvc

I have refer the below link to upload the file but I keep getting

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload

This I have in my Thymeleaf file:

```
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="esubmission/submitter/uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick="disableOnBeforeUnload()" >
         <table>
             <tr>
                 <td><label path="file">Select a file to upload</label></td>
                 <td><input type="file" name="file" /></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my javascript function

```
function disableOnBeforeUnload() {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", windowClosedOrReloaded);
}
```

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, ModelMap modelMap) {
    modelMap.addAttribute("file", file);
    return "fileUploadView";
}
```

As you can see I have the call to function in controller but I am getting 404 error

```
2020-09-07 16:19:05.332 DEBUG 81932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
[2020-09-07 16:19:05,332] DEBUG o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler - Resource not found 
2020-09-07 16:19:05.332 DEBUG 81932 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

What I am missing??

I also tried using ajax call like below:

```
function uploadDocument(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/appName/role/uploadFile/",
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: does this `/appName/role/uploadFile/` url is right ? 404 simply means url which you are referring is not correct or not exist so make sure if the url is correct.

Comment: yes that url is correct. I just changed it to hide the real values.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your path url `/appName/role/uploadFile/` is correct
Because server returning 404 that means path is not correct.
If you are using this script on that same page no need to put `/appname/role/`
you can simply pass that method name as you are on same controller.